# Why I needed to recreate the composer autoloader inside the Homestead VM via ssh?

Tags: php, vagrant, homestead, psr-4

My project has the following file structure:

```
|- src
|-- PcMagas
|---- Dropbox.php
|---- DropBoxFactory.php
|- web
|-- index.php
```

And anything in the src folder is getting autoloaded as PSR-4 dictates via composer:

```
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4":{
            "": "src/"
        }
    }
```

A sample of a class Located in `src/PCMagas` is:

```
namespace PCMagas;

use \GuzzleHttp\Client; 
use PCMagas\Exceptions\FileNotFoundException;

class DropboxFactory
{
    public static function fomeFunc()
    {
       //Do stuff
    }
}
```

And On `index.php` I use the class like that:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
use PCMagas\DropboxFactory;
DropboxFactory::fomeFunc();
```

Whilst Homestead's **host** I launch my app via:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
cd ^project_root^/web
php -S localhost:8990
```

The output of the commands are:

```
$ composer dump-autoload -o

No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/datawise? [Y,n]? Y
Generating optimized autoload files
```

And for the `php -S localhost:8990` is:

```
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 Development Server started at Mon Apr 22 15:46:06 2019
Listening on http://localhost:8990
Document root is /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/php/apps/datawise/web
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

And have no issues whatever. But when I try to launch via homestead I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PCMagas\DropboxFactory' not found in /home/vagrant/code/web/index.php

Via doing:

```
vagrant ssh
```

And afterwards:

```
cd ~/code
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Worked like a charm, but still I have the following questions:

1. Why on the `host` (outside of Homestead-running vm) the classes being autoloaded whilst inside is not? Is it because `./vendor` folder is `.gitignore`d?
2. How I can automatically provision in order on Vm setup to autoload the PSR-4 namespaced classes? Does the `after.sh` run as root or as a the non-root user `vagrant` that in the `/home/vagrant/code` my application is located?

Comment: Can you try this please

`cd ^project_root^
composer dump-autoload -o
php -S localhost:8990`

Comment: The webpage is loaded from `web` folder.

Comment: Added the output to the edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question `2` you can find out the user via placing on your project's `after.sh` the following code:

```
echo "I am user ${USER}"
```

And run the command `vagrant provision` if the output is:

> I am user vagrant

Then the following piece of code in `after.sh` should do the job:

```
cd ~/code
composer install
composer dump-autoload -o
cd
```

For the first one I still have no answer to give you.